# NoSuchMethodError for XmlSchemaCollection.read()

Tags: java, xml, spring

I keep geting NoSuchMethodError for XmlSchemaCollection.read(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;), I found that there is problem in older versions of XMLSchema [What happened to: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(InputSource)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031947/what-happened-to-org-apache-ws-commons-schema-xmlschemacollection-readinputsou).
I changed maven dependency but error keep repeating.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;)Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema;
at org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.afterPropertiesSet(CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.java:137)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 55 more
```

maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

schema collection bean

```
<bean id="schemaCollection" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
    <property name="xsds" value="/message.xsd"/>
    <property name="inline" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Take a look at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729062/nosuchmethoderror-for-xmlschemacollection-read

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031947/what-happened-to-org-apache-ws-commons-schema-xmlschemacollection-readinputsou

Answer (score 4):

It might be that some other library is depending on older version of xmlschema-core.
check

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

if you see xmlschema-core in dome other library as dependency, then try to exclude it by using exclusion on parent dependency
[see Dependency Exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

The other option is; 
if you have a problem or missing artifactId in your projects pom.xml, this problem persists too.