# dependencies for same jar having different trees

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, dependencies

I am trying to resolve an issue with a spring jar. I am using very old jars for A very old project.

For one project my dependency tree is having spring-core 2.0.1 and for the other it is having Spring-core 2.0.2 now. they both are coming as a dependency of one jar : spring-ws-core:jar:1.0-m3.

The issue I am having is the exception below: it turns out that the ClassUtils was changed from 2.0.1 to 2.0.2 and missed out this method. :

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 94) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityLoadJob' defined in class path resource [dri-applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getConstructorIfAvailable(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:443)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:156)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getConstructorIfAvailable(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.<clinit>(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:60)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:52)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:626)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:381)
        ... 20 more



[INFO] com.sar.registry:MyServlet:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.sar.registry:DirectRegistry:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sar.common:Common-Utils:jar:SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sar.common:Common-Integration:jar:SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0.1:compile
***[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:1.0-m3:compile***
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:1.0-m3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-support:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0:compile (version managed from 1.0.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
***[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.0.1:compile***
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-oxm:jar:1.0-m3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-security:xmlsec:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- wss4j:wss4j:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.16:provided (scope managed from compile)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- quartz:quartz:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO] +- com.sar.registry:MyAppApi:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:8.7:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jmx:jar:2.0.1:runtime
[INFO] +- net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:jar:8.7:runtime
[INFO] +- axis:axis:jar:1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- axis:axis-wsdl4j:jar:1.5.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-mock:jar:2.0.1:test
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] \- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and for the other:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ MyApp ---
[INFO] com.sar.registry:MyApp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.sar.registry:MyAppApi:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.sar.common:Common-Utils:jar:SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.sar.common:Common-Integration:jar:SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0.1:compile
***[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:1.0-m3:compile***
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:1.0-m3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-support:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0:compile (version managed from 1.0.1)
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
***[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.0.2:compile***
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-oxm:jar:1.0-m3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- xml-security:xmlsec:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- wss4j:wss4j:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- quartz:quartz:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.8:test
[INFO] +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-mock:jar:2.0.1:test
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:test
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:8.7:test (scope not updated to runtime)
[INFO] +- net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:jar:8.7:test
[INFO] \- axis:axis:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    +- axis:axis-wsdl4j:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO]    \- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:test
```

in my poms, I am not defining any versions for Spring-beans and Spring-core the only version I have defined is in the parent Pom which is org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:1.0-m3:compile

Now how can two projects having the same jar can have different dependent jars altogether. I am on Maven3, wildfly9, java8.

Also, Somehow and strangely, the same war file works fine on my local windows wildfly9 but it gives me error on  a SunOS and Linux machine.

Edit:
I got the dependencyTree Idea from [NoSuchMethodError for XmlSchemaCollection.read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729062/nosuchmethoderror-for-xmlschemacollection-read)
and using that I found the two jars. As Harini suggested, I had already tried exclusion of the dependency and it still didn't work So I just refactored my code to have only one src and that too in the war (In wildfly war is loaded in its own classloader with its libs) So after refactoring as well, I got the same issue:

How I got to know that it was the jar issue was I did a verbose on my jvm and saw this:

[Loaded org.springframework.util.ClassUtils from vfs:/content/DirectRegistryServlet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-2.0.1.jar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon looking at the code of org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean which I am using which is actually the one causing the issue it turns out that in spring 2.0.1 this FactoryBean does not have any mention of the ClassUtils.getConstructorIfAvailable which is good. It is the Spring-2.0.2 OR spring-support-2.0.2.jar That also has this class with this line where this call is.

(I was looking at the wrong class as the issue the issue was MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean coming from a different jar instead of coming from spring-2.0.1.jar, Spring-ws-2.0.1actually uses spring-mvc which uses spring-support2.0.2.jar which had the same MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean  ) SO I solved it: Made only one library to get the MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean removed the library or excluded the library that also had this class and solved it.

Strangely I cant understand how on windows it was working without an issue and on Linux and unix it gave an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the spring-ws-core:jar:1.0-m3 dependency exclude the spring-core version which you are not using.Check it out for Dependency Exclusions.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html